# Using pandas to merge data and output Json

Tags: python, json, csv, pandas

I have several different CSV files like this:

```
one: 

iq, name 
69, joe
122, james
...

two:

iq_start, iq_end, category
120,500, Very Superior
120,129,    Superior
110,119,    High Average
90,109, Average
80,89,  Low Average
70,79,  Borderline
0,69,   Extremely Low

three: 
iq, career
69 , manual work
122, doctor
```

I want to pull the data into pandas , and output the data like this

```
[
"122" = {
    "name" : "james",
    "career" : "doctor"
    "category" : "Superior"
    },

"69" = {
    "name" : "joe",
    "career" : "manual work"
    "category" : "Extremely Low"
    }


]
```

Can panda pull this off or get me some of the way?

Comment: You could probably even do that without pandas, with the `csv` and `json` modules. With pandas should work fine as well, but what have you tried already?

Comment: I know I can do it without Pandas, but I'm wondering if I can do it in Pandas. for example can you do a join like `iq between iq_start and iq_end` in pandas?

Comment: Well, Pandas has a [csv](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/generated/pandas.read_csv.html#pandas.read_csv) import, and Series and Dataframes have a [`to_json`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_json.html#pandas-dataframe-to-json) method, so this should definitely be possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the code, but are you sure there are not two person with the same IQ?

```
import pandas as pd
import io

one="""iq, name
69, joe
120, james"""

two="""iq_start, iq_end, category
130,500, Very Superior
120,129,    Superior
110,119,    High Average
90,109, Average
80,89,  Low Average
70,79,  Borderline
0,69,   Extremely Low"""

three="""iq, career
69 , manual work
120, doctor"""

df1 = pd.read_csv(io.BytesIO(one), skipinitialspace=True)
df2 = pd.read_csv(io.BytesIO(two), skipinitialspace=True)
df3 = pd.read_csv(io.BytesIO(three), skipinitialspace=True)

iqmap = pd.Series(df2.category.values, index=df2.iq_start).sort_index()

df = pd.merge(df1, df3)
df["category"] = iqmap.asof(df.iq).values
df.set_index("iq", inplace=True)
df.T.to_dict()
```

output:

```
{69: {'career': 'manual work', 'category': 'Extremely Low', 'name': 'joe'},
 120: {'career': 'doctor', 'category': 'Superior', 'name': 'james'}}
```

Comment: Thanks, that will get me started. The data is only a sample. The real data the "iq" is unique